# Express 4 router.route: route not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm running into a strange issue. The first route is working, but the parameterized route returns a 404 error.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/')
    .get(function (req, res, next) {
        res.send('A list of vehicles.');
    })
    .post(function (req, res, next) {
        res.send('You added a vehicle!');
    });

router.route('/:id')
    .get(function (req, res, next, id) {
        res.send('Vehicle: ' + id);
    })
    .put(function (req, res, next, id) {
        res.send('You edited vehicle: ' + id);
    });
```

If I add this route:

```
router.route('/test')
    .get(function (req, res, next) {
        res.send('This is a test.');
    });
```

...I can hit that endpoint. This also seems to work with another router I'm using, which is using `router.get(path, function)` and `router.post(path, function)` instead of the `router.route(path).get()...` methodology.

Am I missing something obvious here? I'm using Express ~4.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gah, I'm an idiot. Just figured this out. I saw an example that used this function signature:

```
.get(function (req, res, next, id) {
        res.send('Vehicle: ' + id);
    })
```

This apparently doesn't work. I'm not sure if the http methods check the arity of the function, but this did work:

```
.get(function (req, res, next) {
        res.send('Vehicle: ' + req.params.id);
    })
```

I don't remember where I saw that example, but hopefully this helps someone.